# PyQt having a status bar & menu bar QWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qwidget, qmainwindow

I am trying to create a PyQt application that has both status bar and a menu bar with other Widgets in the window. Below is the code which I managed to get it run with class `QtGui.QMainWindow` method. But as I intend to add further features, I realise I must use `QtGui.QWidget` instead.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

### How can I use QtGui.QWidget here??? ###

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):                                  
     def __init__(self):
          super(Example, self).__init__()
          self.initUI()

     def initUI(self):               

        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))    
        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> Window widget')

        exitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit-icon-2.png'), '&Exit', self)

        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')                        
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit/Terminate application')   

        exitAction.triggered.connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)           

        self.statusBar()                                       

        menubar = self.menuBar()                                
        menubar.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> for MenuBar')                                

        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')                     
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)                          
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')                       
        toolbar.addAction(exitAction)                           

        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)                  

        qbtn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')  
        qbtn.clicked.connect(self.launchAAA)                    
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())                           
        qbtn.move(170, 190)                                     



        self.setGeometry(500, 180, 400, 400)                    
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button with Message')        
        self.show()                                            

    def launchAAA(self, event):

        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
        "Are you sure to quit?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | 
        QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:  
           QtGui.QApplication.quit()
        else:
           pass                                              


def main():

   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)                          
   ex=Example()

   sys.exit(app.exec_())                                       


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

I am under the impression that menu bar and title bars can be created using QWidget method, but here it doesn't work. I intend to add an LCD function to the application using `QtGui.QLCDNumber`.

Any suggestions on how to fix the above problem. Thanks

Comment: @Mailerdaimon QWidget is having features like LCD Display, vbox and hbox functions that I might later need? I feel confused at your question, can you please tell me more.

Comment: A normal approach is to create a QMainWindow and set a central QWidget for this Window using  `void QMainWindow::setCentralWidget(QWidget * widget)`. Plus: QMainWindow is inherited from QWidget which means it has all the features a QWidget has plus more.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon so QMainWindow has all the inherited features from QWidget so it should be fine to use it. And setting a central QWidget should fix my problems, can you guide me on any changes that would go on the above code?

Comment: What you are missing is adding the `qbtn` to the QMainWindow. You can either do this directly by using `setCentralWidget` or, what I suggest, create a new Widget and set a Layout to this Widget, add your `qbtn` to the Layout and set the Widget as centralWidget. This allows you to add multiple layouts and widgets to the main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution using your code. I added a `centralWidget` and a `centralLayout` to the `QMainWindow` which now holds your `qbtn`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):                                  
     def __init__(self):
          super(Example, self).__init__()
          self.initUI()

     def initUI(self):               

        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))    
        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> Window widget')

        exitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit-icon-2.png'), '&Exit', self)

        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')                        
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit/Terminate application')   

        exitAction.triggered.connect(QtGui.qApp.quit)           

        self.statusBar()                                       

        menubar = self.menuBar()                                
        menubar.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> for MenuBar')                                

        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')                     
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)                          
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')                       
        toolbar.addAction(exitAction)                        

        # Create a central Widgets
        centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()

        # Create a Layout for the central Widget
        centralLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()



        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)                  

        qbtn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')  
        qbtn.clicked.connect(self.launchAAA)                    
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())                           
        qbtn.move(170, 190)      

        # Add the Button to the Layout
        centralLayout.addWidget(qbtn)  

        # Set the Layout
        centralWidget.setLayout(centralLayout)

        # Set the Widget
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)     

        self.setGeometry(500, 180, 400, 400)                    
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button with Message')        
        self.show()                                            

     def launchAAA(self, event):

        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
        "Are you sure to quit?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | 
        QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:  
           QtGui.QApplication.quit()
        else:
           pass                                              


def main():

   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)                          
   ex=Example()

   sys.exit(app.exec_())                                       


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: The code seems to work fine, with some fine tuning. But I couldn't get the pushbutton to hold its size as we increase or decrease the window size. `qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())` seem to have no effect in this. Any changes that I should make?

Comment: I think this should be a new question. This makes it easier for others to find the solution if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could just move your buttons/labels/etc. to a `QWidget`, and add this widget to the main window. Here is how it could look like (I changed the imports so that it is a bit more readable).

*Your content widget class :*

```
class ExampleContent(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):        
        qbtn = QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        qbtn.clicked.connect(self.launchAAA)                 
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())                           
        qbtn.move(170, 190)

    def launchAAA(self):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
        "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes | 
        QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:  
            QApplication.quit()
        else:
            pass
```

*Add it to the main window :*

```
class Example(QMainWindow):                                  
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        self.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> Window widget')

        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit-icon-2.png'), '&Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit/Terminate application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        self.statusBar()

        menubar = self.menuBar()        
        menubar.setToolTip('This is a <b>QWidget</b> for MenuBar')

        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        toolbar.addAction(exitAction)

        # create the widget here
        content = ExampleContent(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(content)

        self.setGeometry(500, 180, 400, 400)     
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button with Message')
        self.show()
```

And everything just works as before, except that you new have a `QWidget` in the middle, instead of a `QMainWindow`. Hope that helped !

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a combination of QMainWindow and QWidget.

I have found this useful in some cases. You can add statusbar and menubar to the MainWindow section and the widgets to the QWidget area.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self, parent=None):

    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

    self.win_widget = WinWidget(self)
    widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)
    layout.addWidget(self.win_widget)
    self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 450, 250)
    self.setWindowTitle('Test')  
    self.setWindowIcon (QtGui.QIcon('logo.png'))
    self.show()

    self.win_widget = WinWidget (self)



class WinWidget (QtGui.QWidget) : 

def __init__(self, parent): 
    super (WinWidget , self).__init__(parent)
    self.__controls()
    #self.__layout()

def __controls(self):

    self.qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
    self.qbtn. clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
    self.qbtn.setFixedSize (100,25)
    self.qbtn.move(50, 50)  


def main():

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```